# Spark fp growth is not giving multiple items in consequent

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am using spark fp growth algorithm. I have given minsupport and confidence as o, so all combinations i should get

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, [1, 2, 5]),
    (1, [1, 2, 3, 5]),
    (2, [1, 2])
], ["id", "items"])

fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.0, minConfidence=0.0)
model = fpGrowth.fit(df)

# Display generated association rules.
model.associationRules.show()
```

First problem is always my consequent contain only one element

[1] -> [5, 2] should be a sample output freq of 1 is 3, freq of 5,2 is 2 and freq of [5, 2, 1]|  is 2. so This should come in rules

Comment: "problem is always my consequent contain only one element" - that's how FPGrowth works. Rules are of form 1..N (antecedent) -> 1 (consequent).

Comment: can you please give me any document which says that?

Answer (score 0):

The spark implementation is such that it would only return 1 element in the consequent.
You can check the same in the below link.
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/fpm/AssociationRules.scala

```
//the consequent contains always only one element
itemSupport.get(consequent.head))
```

This is from the MLlib package(ML package uses MLlib implementation).

Cheers,